# Is there a way to restrict number of connections to a specific port in a Twisted protocol server?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I have a python Twisted server application interfacing with a legacy client application and each client has been assigned a specific port on which to connect to the server.  So I have set up listeners on all those ports on the server and it is working beautifully, but I need to build in some safeguards to disallow more than one client connecting on the same server port.  There are too many things on the client application that break when another client is connected to the same port, and I can't update that application right now.  I gotta live with how it has been operating.
I know that I could build in some logic to the connectionMade() function to see if someone already exists on that port and if so, close this new connection.  But I'd rather there be a way to reject it to begin with, so the client is not even allowed to connect.  Then the client will know they made a mistake and they can alter which port they are trying to connect on.

Here is a stripped down version of my server code if that helps.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
import time

class MyServerTasks():
    def someFunction(msg):
        #Do stuff

    def someOtherFunction(msg):
        #Do other stuff

class MyServer(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None

    def connectionMade(self):
        #Depending on which port is connected, go do stuff

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        #Update dictionaries and other global info

    def dataReceived(self, line):
        t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        d = self.transport.getHost()
        print("{} Received message from {}:{}...{}".format(t, d.host, d.port, line))  #debug
        self.handle_GOTDATA(line)

    def handle_GOTDATA(self, msg):
        #Parse the received data string and do stuff based on the message.
        #For example:
        if "99" in msg:
            MyServerTasks.someFunction(msg)

class MyServerFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

    def buildProtocol(self, *args, **kwargs):
        protocol = MyServer(self.users)
        protocol.factory = self
        protocol.factory.clients = []
        return protocol

reactor.listenTCP(50010, MyServerFactory())
reactor.listenTCP(50011, MyServerFactory())
reactor.listenTCP(50012, MyServerFactory())
reactor.listenTCP(50013, MyServerFactory())

reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a client connected to the server, `twisted` use the `factory` to create 
a `protocol` (by calling its `buildProtocol` method) instance to handle the client request.

therefore you can maintain a counter of connected client in your `MyServerFactory`,
if the counter has reached maximum allowed connected client you can return `None` 
instead of creating new protocol for that client.
Twisted will close the client connection if the factory doesn't return a protocol from 
its `buildProtocol` method.

[you can see here](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/8c251edc95b48d578660343c5de072691ff75e8b/src/twisted/internet/tcp.py#L1428)

```
class MyServer(Protocol):

def __init__(self, users):
    self.users = users
    self.name = None

def connectionMade(self):
    #Depending on which port is connected, go do stuff

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    #Update dictionaries and other global info
    self.factory.counter -= 1

def dataReceived(self, line):
    t = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    d = self.transport.getHost()
    print("{} Received message from {}:{}...{}".format(t, d.host, d.port, line))  #debug
    self.handle_GOTDATA(line)

def handle_GOTDATA(self, msg):
    #Parse the received data string and do stuff based on the message.
    #For example:
    if "99" in msg:
        MyServerTasks.someFunction(msg)



 class MyServerFactory(Factory):
   MAX_CLIENT = 2

 def __init__(self):
    self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances
    self.counter = 0

 def buildProtocol(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.counter == self.MAX_CLIENT:
        return None
    self.counter += 1
    protocol = MyServer(self.users)
    protocol.factory = self
    protocol.factory.clients = []
    return protocol
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, this is supposed to count ALL client connections and limit server connections to 1.  That is getting closer, but I want multiple clients on this server, just that each client should be dedicated to one port.

Comment: But just for fun I modified my code as you proposed and it still allows multiple clients connecting from any port.  I think it has to do with the self.counter  being inside the factory and not a global, so it is reset to 0 every time a user connects?

Comment: in this case you can change the value of MAX_CLIENT to allow only MAX_CLIENT connected to the server, eq. change it to 1 if you want to allow only one client.

The factory instantiated only once, (you instantiate it and you give it as an argument to `reactor.listenTCP`). So there is no reset happen here.

When a client connected the twisted call the factory's  (the one you give to `reactor.listenTCP` as an argument) `buildProtocol` method
not instantiating a new factory and the call its `buildProtocol` method.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you for the clarification.  I misread the logic and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.  I updated with MAX_CLIENT = 1 and it worked.  Only problem is now I need to build in some way to reset that counter when a connection closes, because once a client closes from that port no one is ever allowed to connect to it again!  Perhaps a global variable or dictionary of counters?

Comment: the simplest way without using global variable is to decrement the value of factory.counter by 1 `factory.counter -= 1`  in your `protocol.connectionLost` method.

I have updated the code in my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for all your help.  Exactly what I needed.  Have it running on my server and working beautifully through several tests of multiple connects and disconnects.